# Cairo Perl module installation issue

Tags: perl, perl-module

I am trying to install `Cairo Perl module` locally, but it is throwing me error.

```
$ /testdir/bin/perl -I /testdir/perl-5.14.0/lib Makefile.PL
Package cairo was not found in the pkg-config search path.
Perhaps you should add the directory containing `cairo.pc'
to the PKG_CONFIG_PATH environment variable
No package 'cairo' found
 at Makefile.PL line 99
*** can not find package cairo >= 1.0.0
*** check that it is properly installed and available in PKG_CONFIG_PATH
 at Makefile.PL line 99
```

I can go as suggested by the installer but I am not finding the file called cairo.pc in the installation package. Not sure what I am missing here. Please help me out.

Comment: Did you download Cairo from CPAN?  Which module does the `Makefile.PL` belong to?

Comment: yes , i downloaded it from CPAN , http://search.cpan.org/dist/Cairo/

Answer (score 2):

The module only contains the Perl bindings for Cairo. You'll need to have the C library (with the C headers) installed first, otherwise there is nothing for those bindings to bind to.

http://cairographics.org/download/ is a good place to start for working out where to get those from (it varies depending on your OS).

Comment: Hi , Can you please explain further on this issue, I am using Solaris

Comment: The Cairo Perl module isn't Cairo. It is a way to use Cairo from Perl. You have to install Cairo first.

Answer (score 0):

I faced the same issue, seeing Quentin answer it's clear that you need to install Cairo first. I did the below and Cairo got installed successfully.

For Debian and Debian derivatives including Ubuntu:

```
sudo apt-get install libcairo2-dev
```

For Fedora:

```
sudo yum install cairo-devel
```

For openSUSE:

```
zypper install cairo-devel
```

Now install the Perl module

```
cpan Cairo
```

or

```
cpanm Cairo
```